# function variable dynamic setting

Tags: javascript, angular, ecmascript-6, anonymous-function, arrow-functions

This question related to Syntactically anonymous/Arrow Function/add-hoc/factory DP functions:
I have a component which is embedded in the Html.
The component has a click event which is binded to a function. This function content depend on another component which has a reference to this component.
This is the component with the click event:
HTML:

```
<div  (click)="doSomething()">Content.....</div> \\ Should it be with a brackets ?
```

In the component I just want to define the function signature:

```
@Component({
 selector: 'app-embedded'
})
export class className 
{
  constructor() { }
  ngOnInit() {   }
  doSomething:(booleanparams: boolean) => any; //The function get a boolean parameter as input and return void or any
}
```

Now this is where the component is embedded:

```
<div >
    <app-embedded #emb></app-embedded>
</div>
```

This is the component of the container of the embedded component, which has a reference to the embedded component:

```
@Component({
 selector: 'app-container',
})
export class container
{
   @ViewChild('emb') private emb: ElementRef;
   booleanParam : booelan;
   constructor()
   {
      emb.doSomething = containerFunction(true);
   }

   containerFunction(booleanParam : boolean)
   { 
       // do something in this context
   }
}
```

The idea is that this embedded component is embedded in many other containers and whenever the click event triggered a function that was set in the doSomething function variable should be executed.

What changes in the code I need to do in order to accomplish this ?

Answer (score 0):

The best way i see of doing this would be to simply use an event emitter and capture the event on the other side? so embedded would have this:

```
@Component({
 selector: 'app-embedded'
})
export class className 
{

  @Output()
  public something: EventEmitter<boolean> = new EventEmitter<boolean>();

  constructor() { }
  ngOnInit() {   }
  doSomething:(booleanparams: boolean) {
    this.something.emit(booleanparams);
  }; //The function get a boolean parameter as input and return void or any
}
```

Then where it is called:

```
<div >
    <app-embedded #emb (something)="doSomething($event)"></app-embedded>
</div>
```

Other solution that would allow a return

```
@Component({
 selector: 'app-embedded'
})
export class className 
{

  @Input()
  public somethingFunc: (boolean)=>any;

  constructor() { }
  ngOnInit() {   }
  doSomething:(booleanparams: boolean) {
    let w_potato = this.somethingFunc(booleanparams); 
    //Do whatever you want with w_potato
  }; //The function get a boolean parameter as input and return void or any
}
```

in this case the view would be

```
<div >
    <app-embedded #emb [somethingFunc]="doSomething"></app-embedded>
</div>
```

I hope this helps! Passing the function or emitting an event will be much more angular than trying to modify an instance of a component. On top of that, a constructor is only called once when Angular starts up so #emb at that time will not be defined to be anything. If you wanted to do it that way you would have to bind yourself in something ngAfterViewInit. 
But again, I think that passing it through attributes will be much more angular looking.

Good Luck let me know if this doesn't suit your answer.

Comment: Thank you, I'll try it, although the function type parameter is prefered by me right now. Thanks again